# Android - Limit only one decimal point enter into a TextView

Tags: android, textview, decimal

I need help to only allow one decimal point to be entered into a TextView. An example: I don't want 123.45.2 or 123..452 to be allowed. Once one decimal point is entered, no more are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your EditText, this will take care of the decimal.

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"    
/>
```

Comment: mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL); try adding this.

Comment: Where will i insert that? onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val yourString = "11.232.142"
val parts = yourString.split(".")
val result = parts.take(2).filter { it.isNotBlank() }.joinToString(".")

textView.text = result
```